# Setas Next e Prev em Slider

Tags: jquery, html

Estou tentando mudar de imagem usando as setas **NEXT** e **PREV**.

### HTML

```
<div id="imagem-galeria">
    {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/galeria/foto-grande-1.jpg', 'Peças Colhedora de Cana', ['class' => 'img-main']) !!}
    {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/seta-direita.png', 'Seta Direita', ['class' => 'seta-direita'] ) !!}
    {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/seta-esquerda.png', 'Seta Esquerda', ['class' => 'seta-esquerda'] ) !!}
</div>

<div class="owl-carousel-galeria">
    <div class="item change-image"><div class="square"></div> {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/galeria/torcane-foto-thumb-1.jpg', 'Foto 1') !!}</div>
    <div class="item change-image"><div class="square"></div> {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/galeria/torcane-foto-thumb-2.jpg', 'Foto 2') !!}</div>
    <div class="item change-image"><div class="square"></div> {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/galeria/torcane-foto-thumb-3.jpg', 'Foto 3') !!}</div>
    <div class="item change-image"><div class="square"></div> {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/galeria/torcane-foto-thumb-4.jpg', 'Foto 4') !!}</div>
    <div class="item change-image"><div class="square"></div> {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/galeria/torcane-foto-thumb-5.jpg', 'Foto 5') !!}</div>
    <div class="item change-image"><div class="square"></div> {!! Html::image('img/quem-somos/galeria/torcane-foto-thumb-6.jpg', 'Foto 6') !!}</div>
</div>
```

### jQuery

```
// Próxima Imagem
$('.seta-direita').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
    var imgAtual    = $('.img-main').attr('src');

    // Continuação...
});
```

O elemento `.img-main` é onde vai a foto principal.

Tentei usar o `next()` e o `prev()` do **jQuery**, mas não consegui. 

Qual é o caminho para fazer isso ?

### Solução

### jQuery

```
    var fotos   = new Array();
    fotos[0]    = "foto-grande-1.jpg";
    fotos[1]    = "foto-grande-2.jpg";
    fotos[2]    = "foto-grande-3.jpg";
    fotos[3]    = "foto-grande-4.jpg";
    fotos[4]    = "foto-grande-5.jpg";
    fotos[5]    = "foto-grande-6.jpg";

    // Próxima Imagem
    $('.seta-direita').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
        var imgAtual    = $('.img-main');
        fotoAtual       = fotoAtual + 1;

        if(fotoAtual == 6) 
            fotoAtual = 0;

        imgAtual.attr('src', urlBase + '/img/quem-somos/galeria/' + fotos[fotoAtual]);
    });

    // Anterior Imagem
    $('.seta-esquerda').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
        var imgAtual    = $('.img-main');
        fotoAtual       = fotoAtual - 1;

        if(fotoAtual < 0) 
            fotoAtual = 5;

        imgAtual.attr('src', urlBase + '/img/quem-somos/galeria/' + fotos[fotoAtual]);
    });
```

### Ou

```
var urlsImgs = $.map($(".owl-carousel-galeria").find('img'), function(obj,
    return $(obj).attr('src').replace('thumb', 'grande');
});

// Próxima Imagem
$('.seta-direita').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
    var imgAtual    = $('.img-main');
    fotoAtual++;

    if(fotoAtual >= urlsImgs.length) {
        fotoAtual = 0;
    }
    imgAtual.attr('src', urlsImgs[fotoAtual]);
});

// Próxima Imagem
$('.seta-esquerda').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
    var imgAtual    = $('.img-main');
    fotoAtual--;

    if(fotoAtual < 0) {
        fotoAtual = (urlsImgs.length - 1);
    }
    imgAtual.attr('src', urlsImgs[fotoAtual]);
});
```

> Pelo Erick Gallani

Comment: Seu código tá muito superficial. O elemento `.img-main` é a imagem que exibe o slide atual provavelmente, certo ? Porque então pegar o `src` e não da imagem alvo? O que essa template `{!!  .. !!}` gera, elementos `img` ? Não conheço essa template, também não tem tag dela. Podia postar o código gerado, talvez fosse mais fácil pra nós. Se são gerados `img` não teria como usar `next()` e `prev()`. E o que é `imgAtual`, algum outro código lê essa variável ?

Comment: Diego qual componente jquery esta usando?  $('.img-main') é o container onde fica a imagem principal que deve ficar mudando?

Comment: @ErickGallani, exatamente. Editei meu post explicando isso.

Comment: veja se isso pode lhe ajudar http://jsfiddle.net/8WTer/

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, o elemento `.img-main` é a foto principal. Clicar na foto do slider e mostrar na principal já está sendo feito. Mas eu quero fazer com setas também. Estou usando `Laravel 5`, não coloquei a **tag** porquê a minha necessidade não tem nada a ver com `Laravel`.

Comment: @ThiagoFriedman, legal... mas tem que baixar o Cycle. Minha última alternativa é usar um plugin.

Comment: Entendi, é que não conheço aquela sintaxe então se tivesse a tag eu procuraria e entenderia, porque não da pra saber se é server-side ou não. Ou então, como eu disse se você postasse com o código final, o gerado por essa template também resolveria. Mas ok.

Comment: A síntaxe só monta o `<img>`. Pra não escrever `<img src=...>` eu faço `{!! HTML::image('caminho') !!}`. E assim vai...

Comment: Notei que você adicionou a solução na própria pergunta e aceitou outra como a melhor resposta. Será que você poderia editar e adicionar a solução como uma resposta? Não me entenda mal, apenas acho que seria melhor como resposta.

Comment: Não poderia. Att, Diego.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Diego.

Imagino que o problema seja o seguinte.

Fazendo isso

```
var imgAtual = $('.img-main').attr('src');
```

Você está pegando o source da imagem sendo exibida e atribuindo ela a uma variável e ponto final, mais nada.

Na verdade você tem que alterar o source da imagem principal, fazendo assim.

```
$('.img-main').attr('src', urlDaImagem);
```

No evento de click.

O ideal era quando o DOM da página carregar armazenar todas as referências das imagens dentro da div **owl-carousel-galeria** em um array e então mudar a imagem no next e prev do **img-main** ao clicar nos respectivos eventos.

Tipo assim.

```
$('.seta-direita').on(clickDeviceEvent, function(){
    $('.img-main').attr('src', refsImgs[indexAtual]);
});
```

Onde **refsImgs** são todas URLs das imagens e **indexAtual** uma variável global armazenando o index atual do seu carrossel.

Legal que conseguiu!

Vou dar uma sugestão de implementação aqui, menos estático e mais dinâmico.

```
var indexAtual = 0;

        $(document).ready(function(){

            var urlsImgs = $.map($(".owl-carousel-galeria").find('img'), function(obj, index) { return $(obj).attr('src') });

            $('.seta-direita').on('click', function(){

                indexAtual++;

                if(indexAtual >= urlsImgs.length) {
                    indexAtual = 0; //se chegou ao final do array, volta para o primeiro item
                }

                $('.img-main').attr('src', urlsImgs[indexAtual]);
            });

            $('.seta-esquerda').on('click', function(){

                indexAtual--;

                if(indexAtual < 0) {
                    indexAtual = (urlsImgs.length - 1); //se chegou ao começo do array, volta para o úlitmo item
                }

                $('.img-main').attr('src', urlsImgs[indexAtual]);
            });
        });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aykoga40/

Comment: Mano, isso é o código que comecei, não o final. Eu peguei o `src` da foto principal para fazer a substituição...

Comment: Certo, consegui entender seu problema. Veja minha última edição da resposta. Caso precise de mais ajuda com o código podemos ir lapidando para te ajudar.

Comment: Aí Mano ! Consegui usando sua lógica. Por isso que eu perguntei: qual é o caminho para fazer isso ? E você deu o caminho e não a solução pronta. Entendeu mesmo minha pergunta. Obrigado. Vou postar na minha pergunta a solução.

Comment: @DiegoSouza perfeito. Dei uma sugestão de implementação na minha resposta. Valeu =D

Comment: O que essa linha faz ? `var urlsImgs = $.map($(".owl-carousel-galeria").find('img'), function(obj, index) { return $(obj).attr('src') });`, coloca num **Array** ?

Comment: Mapeia todas as imgs dentro da div que contem a classe owl-carousel-galeria e gera um array com todas as URLs das imgs. Assim você pode adicionar e retirar as imgs da div como quiser sem se preocupar em alterar o array na mão por ter adicionado ou tirado alguma imagem do seu carrossel. Mais infos em http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/

Comment: Pronto, fiz desse jeito, realmente será mais fácil futuramente caso eu queira aumentar ou diminuir. Só tive que dar um `replace` no momento que vai colocar a foto na principal, porquê as imagens que estão no `.owl-carousel-galeria` são thumbnails, ou seja, o nome é diferente.

Comment: @DiegoSouza perfeito. Assim você aumenta a manutenabilidade da sua aplicação.

Comment: Eu posso dar o `replace` na função, né ? No `return` ? Sim, deu certo.

Comment: Pode sim. Fica melhor até

Answer (score 0):

para resolver adicione o css:

```
 .slick-prev:before,
    .slick-next:before {
      color: black !important;
    }
```

Caso as classes tenham mudado, basta entrar na pasta do slick e verificar no arquivo index.html que tem os exemplos, e você pode ver o nome das classes das setas.